# Codeigniter: The problem is in the if else. it only work only on IF it won't go to else if

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

Good day sirs. Please help me i'm stuck with this problem. i have 2 book information form and now my goal is to allow the librarian to insert to database even only 1 form have value no matter what form librarian choose [! actually it can insert but only the left side form the right side it have error

UPDATE:
when i check it won't go to else if

for some reason i cant put screenshot
the error:
"Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lnulibrary`.`tbl_borrowed_books`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_borrowed_books_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_books` (`book_id`))

INSERT INTO `tbl_borrowed_books` (`book_id`, `profile_id`, `return_date`) VALUES ('', '1', '2021-11-11')

Filename: D:/new xampp/htdocs/library/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691"

[image: The forms]
[image: the error if i choose the right book information form]

```
 my model
 public function borrowers()
  {

 $sum =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
  $isbn1= $this->input->post('serial1',true);
   $isbn2= $this->input->post('serial2',true);

  if(empty($isbn2))
  {
   $data1 = array(
  'book_id'     => $this->input->post('book_id1',true),
  'profile_id'  => $this->input->post('userid',true),
  'return_date' => $sum

    );
      $this->db->insert('tbl_borrowed_books', $data1);

      }
      if(empty($isbn1))
      {
       $data2 = array(
      'book_id'     => $this->input->post('book_id2',true),
      'profile_id'  => $this->input->post('userid',true),
      'return_date' => $sum


      );
      $this->db->insert('tbl_borrowed_books', $data2);
        }



    /* i will use this if 2 forms have value */
/* $data1 = array(
    'book_id'     => $this->input->post('book_id1',true),
   'profile_id'  => $this->input->post('userid',true),
   'return_date' => $sum

   );
   $this->db->insert('tbl_borrowed_books', $data1);

   $data2 = array(
  'profile_id'  => $this->input->post('userid',true),
  'book_id'     => $this->input->post('book_id2',true),
  'return_date' => $sum

          );
        $this->db->insert('tbl_borrowed_books', $data2);*/

       }
```

Comment: Is `tbl_borrowed_books.book_id` expected to be an integer?  (I kind of expect it to be an integer)  If it is autoincremented, either omit that column from the INSERT syntax or grab the `$this->db->insert_id()` from the row INSERTed into the parent table.  I have little confidence in this suggestion because the English / [mcve] isn't ultra-clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the correct bookid, ie the one that is present in your database,
This is not an error with codeigniter it's an error with database, you can remove the foreign key and check debug, but I highly recommend you to use foreign key